# Looping in vertical position

Tags: java

I am a beginner in `java` and i will like to seek some help.

Write a method called vertical that accepts a String as its parameter and prints each letter of the string on separate lines. For example, a call of vertical("hey now") should produce the following output:

```
h
e
y

n
o
w
```

This is what i have done.

```
public void vertical(String x){
    char OneByOne='x';
        for(int i=0;i<=x.length()-1;i++){
            OneByOne=x.charAt(i);
        }
        System.out.print(OneByOne);
}
```

It gives me w when i call for it.
But i am confused.i create a char container and call out position 0.And loop through it.Shouldn't position 0 
starts from h.Instead of giving me a w?

Also,should i use `public void vertical(String x){ or public static void vertical(String x){`?They give me the same output.I go research on static and they tell me static means single.What does that means?

Comment: Move System.out.print(OneByOne); into the loop and change print to println

Comment: And use `println` instead of `print`

Comment: I see it finally.Been too tired practising.I have to move inside the loop because it will then print every value right?If not it will keep looping until last char which is w and print it right?

Comment: Exactly, it loops over the string and then prints the value that remains in the variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void vertical(String x){
    int count = x.length();
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
       System.out.println(x.charAt(i));
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not printing inside the loop. Also, use println.

Answer (score 1):

you need to print char in each iteration.

```
public void vertical(String x){
    char OneByOne='x';
        for(int i=0;i<=x.length()-1;i++){
            System.out.println(x.charAt(i));
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers: You can also use a for each loop:

```
public static void vertical(String x) {
    for (char OneByOne : x.toCharArray()) {
        System.out.println(OneByOne);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a more conventional style here:

```
public void vertical(String x){
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++){
        char oneByOne = x.charAt(i);
        System.out.println(oneByOne);
    }
}
```

Less than length, i.o. less-equals length - 1.

Local declaration. Vars starting with small letter.

The rest is fine. charAt(i) gives the i'th char, just as conceived.

Answer (score 0):

You should use prinln instead of print

```
System.out.println(OneByOne);
```

`static` keyword means you're able to call this method without having an instance of your class.

Comment: instance of my class?Went to research that.Do you mean public class Bicycle {?Means i dont need to create public class Bicycle and i can call the mthod directly?